# dispatchEvent to all listeners

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, event-listener

Perhaps this is a misconception of mine, but I thought that when you create a custom event, and later create "elements with event listeners" (listening for that event), that the event (itself) keeps track of all the listeners who are waiting for the event to occur and that when the event occurs all listeners are automatically notified.

However, in all the examples I've seen, it looks like the notification-process is very explicit (not very automatic); you have to manually code the dispatching of the event to each listening element via:

```
elementName.dispatchEvent(eventName);
```

For example, I just wrote this test-code to:

- create a basic custom event
- generate 100 div elements with listeners for the custom event
- make the background color of each div become red when the event
  happens

```js
var myEvent = new CustomEvent("redTime", {});
var div;
for(var i=1, iL=101; i < iL; i++)
{
  div = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  div.innerHTML = i;
  div.style.border = "solid 1px #333333";
  div.style.display = "inline-block";
  div.style.margin = "1px";
  div.style.padding = "1px";
  div.addEventListener("redTime", function(e)
  {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  });
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
div.dispatchEvent(myEvent);
```

Obviously, I expected the last line of the code above to only make the last div's background color red, but I'm not aware of a method (without creating a loop) to dispatch to all listeners.

However, before trying this experiment, I assumed there would be some method of the event object that would dispatch the event to all subscribed listeners (and make all DIVs red). I thought that was the main purpose of the addEventListener method: to create some type of "behind the scenes list" of all the elements to be notified when an event occurs.

Do you really have to manually dispatch to each element that is listening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A custom event is dispatched to the listeners of a specific target object.  It is not dispatched to all listeners of that event no matter which object the event is dispatched to or which object is being listened to?   It basically works exactly like a 'click' event works.  The event is dispatched only to a specific object and only the listeners for that event attached to that specific object.

If you want a global event and global listeners like you seem to want, then you can create a single known object, have everyone listen to events on that object and then dispatch the event to that object.  Then, everyone will get notified of the event.

You may find it easier to just use an eventEmitter object like [this](https://github.com/Olical/EventEmitter).

But, if all you want to do is to change some attribute of a bunch of `div` objects, then I'd suggest you just put a common class name on them and use `document.querySelectorAll()` to retrieve all the target elements and then run some code on them.  I don't see any particular reason here for custom event listeners as they don't really do what you're doing.

You could use something like this:

```
function iterateTargets(selector, fn, data) {
    var items = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        fn(items[i], data);
    }
}

iterateTargets(".specials", function(item){
    item.style.backgroundColor = "red;
});
```

Or a version that works on a style setting without a callback function:

```
function iterateTargets(selector, fn, data) {
    var items = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        fn(items[i], data);
    }
}

function setStyles(selector, styleName, value) {
    iterateTargets(selector, function(item) {
        item.style[styleName] = value;
    });
}

setStyles(".specials", "backgroundColor", "red");
```

Comment: Added a code example using a common class name and `querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: Thanks. I know how to automate the manual notification via css, html, and js. I'm most interested in the part you said about globally making it to where a bunch of different elements can all get notified at the same time. The code I made was just test-code to achieve this, then I will implement the concept into some modules I've made.

Comment: The key thing is that sometimes, when a piece of data is changed, multiple things need to update due to that event. I can achieve this with functions alone, but I'm trying see if events would be more elegant.

Comment: @LonnieBest - you can create a single `<div>` element that you don't even put in the DOM.  Register all your event listeners on that one element and then dispatch the event to it.  ALL the event listeners will then be called because they are all attached to the same object.  You will then have to keep track of what you want each event listener to do (like modify some other DOM element).  But, I'd personally just use an eventEmitter object rather than that custom event hack.

Comment: @LonnieBest - you can certainly do it all with events, just not using the built-in custom event scheme because it doesn't work the way you do.    You'd just make your own event scheme that works the way you're trying to make it work.